# How to disable query of a keyword in Google?

Tags: web, customization, search-engine

Let's say that I have a set of keywords that I don't want to see in my future Google search results page: `{"Naruto","Toriko","One Piece","Conan"}` (these are names of anime that I want to quit). Is there a way I can write a lightweight script or something so that whenever I use Google, it filters out pages containing those words? Even if I explicitly search for `"Naruto"`, to Google the query is actually `"Naruto -Naruto"` so Google won't return anything. It's easy to ignore certain keywords for a single query using [advanced search](http://www.google.com/advanced_search), but how do I ignore a set of keywords for all my queries in the future?

What is the best way to do this? A Chrome extension? A perl script? A javascript? How can I implement this feature for myself? What tools/languages should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably done best in your browser. For example, you could write a Firefox extension to do this. (It would probably even be worth publishing -- others may want this functionality (like parents).)